# TypeError from tensorlayer ConcatLayer due to tf.concat API change

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorlayer

I am using tensorlayer's concatLayer to concatenate two inputs, one is an embedding, the other is other additional input. the tl.layers.ConcatLayer always runs into the TypeError: "Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead."

Seems tf.concat() api changes may be a cause, but I am using tf 1.2.0 + tensorlayer 1.5.1 (python 2.7.13 | Anaconda 4.3.0)

Can anybody help? Thanks -Wei

network design:

```
emb_net = tl.layers.EmbeddingInputlayer(
    inputs = x,
    vocabulary_size = VOCAB_SIZE,
    embedding_size = FLAGS.embedding_size,
    E_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(
         -FLAGS.init_scale, FLAGS.init_scale),
    name = 'embedding')

word_bound = tl.layers.InputLayer(
    inputs = x_wb,
    name = 'word_boundary')

network = tl.layers.ConcatLayer(
    layer = [emb_net, word_bound],
    concat_dim = 1,
    name = 'concat_layer')
```

Error message:

```
 File "./tensorlayer_lstm_classifier.py", line 147, in do_training
    reuse=None)
  File "./tensorlayer_lstm_classifier.py", line 53, in inference
    name = 'concat_layer')
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers.py", line 4717, in __init__
    self.outputs = tf.concat(concat_dim, self.inputs, name=name)
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1043, in concat
    dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 741, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 374, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/Users/lin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, although still a bit puzzled

in file
anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorlayer/layers.py, line 4717,
just keep the first line of tf.concat()

```
try: # TF1.0
    self.outputs = tf.concat(self.inputs, concat_dim, name=name)
except: # TF0.12
    self.outputs = tf.concat(concat_dim, self.inputs, name=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

could you check the dimension of x and x_wb?

Comment: axis input was corrected to cocat_dim=2 as concat inputs are 3-dimensions